# Sum two dictionaries by values

Tags: python, dictionary, floating-point, sum

I am using python 3.5 and I'm trying to figure out how to sum these two dictionaries by value.

```
{0: [4.3856601065585343e-38], 1: [1.9276743522657556e-08], 2: [3.30408817728935e-147]}

{0: [2.3808784712284318e-28], 1: [1.121936127843438e-67], 2: [3.5039317933946127e-96]}
```

Here is what I have tried

```
def sommadizionari (dict1,dict2):
    lista={ k: [ dict1.values() + dict2.values()] for k in dict1 }
    return lista
```

This is my desired output

```
{0: [4.3856601065585343e-38+2.3808784712284318e-28], 1: [1.9276743522657556e-08+1.121936127843438e-67], 2: [3.30408817728935e-147+3.5039317933946127e-96]}
```

Comment: what if there would be more than 2 dicts with more than 3 items in each dict ?

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
def sommadizionari(dict1, dict2):
    lista = {k: [dict1[k][0] + dict2[k][0]] for k in dict1}
    return lista
```

Remember that `dict1.values()` returns list of all values in dictionary.

Comment: @DavideDiMenna the problem (if it is a problem) is that `2.3808784712284318e-28` is much bigger than `4.3856601065585343e-38`. So sum of this numbers is very close to `2.3808784712284318e-28`